# OpenGL ES 3.1 support (Android L developer preview)

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-5.0-lollipop, opengl-es-3.1

I installed Android L developer preview image on Nexus 5 yesterday in hopes to start implementing compute shaders. The code I expected to give me GLES31 capable OpenGL context is;

```
GLSurfaceView glView = new GLSurfaceView(context);
glView.setEGLContextClientVersion(3);
...
```

The exact same code which creates OpenGL ES 3.0 context on Android 4.4.4.

But instead I am getting OpenGL ES 3.0 context without the new GLES31 capabilities.

Am I missing something fundamental in regard to OpenGL context creation - or is it the case OpenGL ES 3.1 is not supported on current Android L developer preview image (= LPV79)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure that Nexus5 hardware does support OpenGL ES 3.1?

AFAIK Adreno 330 supports only ES 3.0, and ES 3.1 is introduced in Adreno 420 GPU.

Comment: Good question. It never really occurred to me GLES31 and GLES31Ext APIs would be first released on a device that doesn't support them. But since I cannot find any information on OpenGL ES 3.1 support on Adreno 330 need to consider this possibility. Makes me sad to approve this answer though.. Darn..

Comment: I can not find any info if Qualcom will release 3.1 drivers for 330. HW should be able to support it, but drivers are needed. AND are You sure that "(3)" is enough? Is Android pulling 3.1 then? Or is it pulling 3.0, and some other value need to be used for 3.1.

Comment: Not there won't be GLES 3.1 for anything but the 400 series: https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/maximize-hardware/mobile-gaming-graphics-adreno/27936

Comment: @przemo_li according to provided link, Adreno 400 series will also support AEP too, thank you for this useful information.